# Excel 2007/2010/2013 VBA run time error PasteSpecial method of Range class failed

Tags: vba, excel

By below function I'm trying to paste formula in in given column names. below code working fine but when my data goes up to 65K rows it's throwing : PasteSpecial Method range class failed error as well as I find out that in 65K rows when I'm going to run below code the physical memory uses going to be 0 might be this the issue but any one help me to escape or overcome from this issue.

Thanks,

Nikunj

Here, the code details :

Parameters:

1. FormatRng = contains range of format which contains formula
2. DataRng = contais range of on which copied formulae going to be pasted
3. ColArr() = This string array contains columns names in which formula going to be pasted

```
Public Function CompareFormat(FormatRng As Range, DataRng As Range, ColArr() As String)

   Dim ColIndexArr() As Long
   Dim i As Long
   Dim DataColRng As Range
   Dim FormatColRng As Rangeenter 

 ColIndexArr = getCompColumnsPosition(DataRng, ColArr())
 FormatRng.Rows(1).Copy
 DataRng.Rows(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, False, False

Application.CutCopyMode = False

For i = LBound(ColIndexArr) To UBound(ColIndexArr)

    If ColIndexArr(i) > 0 Then

      Set DataColRng = Application.Intersect(DataRng.offset(1, 0), _
        DataRng.Columns(ColIndexArr(i)))
      Set FormatColRng = Application.Intersect(FormatRng.offset(1, 0), _  
        FormatRng.Columns(ColIndexArr(i)))

      FormatColRng.Copy
      DataColRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
      Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End If
Next i
End Function
```

Comment: what happens if you try and copy/paste in chuncks of say, 5000 rows (by making a loop) - this would reduce the load on the processor and memory

Comment: Instead of `Copy` and `PasteSpecial`, have you tried simply: `DataColRnge.Formula = FormatColRng.Formula`?  `Copy` and `Paste` are expensive operations, and can usually be avoided.

Comment: I have tried with chunks logic but it was failed because one formula contains 200+ characters so, might be this issue occuring 

Thanks,

@Philip

Comment: I also used the range to range logic I knew that it consumes less memory it's nice way to copy/paste from clipboard directly but it was not working as I accept it's make excel hang down.

Thanks,

@DavidZemens

Comment: Try disabling screenupdating (`Application.ScreenUpdating = False`) and setting calculation to manual (`Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`) at the beginning of your code. Just make sure to reset them (`Application.ScreenUpdating = True` and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic`) before `End Function`.